# Querying data from sqlite3 database

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to python, kindly need your help. I want to query data from the database and here is my code and am having a typeError. TypeError: query_data() missing 2 required positional arguments:

here is what i have tried and am expecting a list of dictionary[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to post the entire error message.  Also, we need to understand the schema of your database, so include an example of the data being retrieved.  Finally, **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving two arguments to query_data(), while there should be none - the router (/query) does not ask for any single parameter. In other words what you have in the decorator you need to have in function definition.

Comment: How can i get towns that are in the same district? I mean query